# How to Send JSON to a PUT Endpoint with Spring-Webflux

Tags: json, spring-boot, http, spring-webflux, put

I'm trying to send a json String to a put endpoint using webflux.

e.g. say the end point I'm trying to hit is at `http://etc:99999/put/here`, my code looks something like this:

```
@Service
public class someService {
  private final WebClient webClient;

  public someService(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
    this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://etc:9999999/").build();
  }
  
  public Mono<Void> sendPut(String someMessage) {
      return webClient.put()
                    .uri("put/here")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .bodyValue(someMessage)
                    .retrieve();
  }
}
```

However this doesnt appear to hit the endpoint at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that nothing was subscribing to my web-client.
i.e.

```
Mono<void> putStream = webClient.put()
                        .uri("put/here")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .bodyValue(someMessage)
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono();
```

Will not send the put request.

but -

```
Mono<void> putStream = webClient.put()
                        .uri("put/here")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .bodyValue(someMessage)
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono();

putStream.subscribe();
```

Will.

Here's the relevant part of the Reactor docs that helped me figure it out: [Reactor Docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactive.subscribe).